# To read a message from Queueu using xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, ibm-mq, ibm-datapower

I have a scenario as below.

```
Request : MQFSH - > MPGW (We will soter MQ header of request in Q1) --> http backend
Response : http response --> MPGW ( read the MQMD header message stored in Q1 and append to reponse message) -- > MQ
```

please let me know  how to read a message from Q1 in xsl?

Thanks & Reagrds,
Sreevathsa A
9986186302

Comment: This question is extremely unclear.  XSL is a system for transforming XML under control of a stylesheet.  You don't "read a message from a queue using XSL". You might write a program to read a message payload (XML) from a queue and feed it through an XSL processor to produce some output. Please show what you have done so far.  Also, what is "soter"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am able to write and read a message within transform action using xsl.

Writing :

```
<dp:url-open target="dpmq://qmgr/?RequestQueue=queue_name" response="responsecode-ignore">
```

Reading :

```
<dp:url-open target="dpmq://qmgr/?ParseHeaders=true;ReplyQueue=queue_name" response="xml"/>
```

Thanks,
Sreevathsa A

Answer (score 0):

Make a dynamic call to MQ in a variable. Once the request is sent , response will be stored in the variable.

To see the response data you can display the variable or you can store in a context varialbe.

Please see the below example.

```
<xsl:variable name="resultMQ">    
<dp:url-open target="url" response="responsecode-ignore" content-type="text/xml" http-method="post">
        <soapenv:Envelope>
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <Request>
                    <Message>Request you are sending to MQ</Message>
                </Request>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </dp:url-open>

</xsl:variable>
<!-- Storing the MQ result in Context Variable-->
<dp:set-variable name="'var://context/service/MQResult'" value="$resultMQ"/>
```

Comment: Hi Jyo,

My requirement is , store the request message MQMD header into queue in the request rule and in the response rule , read the stored MQMD headers from the queue .

Writing :
<dp:url-open target="dpmq://qmgr/?RequestQueue=queue_name" response="responsecode-ignore">

Reading:
<dp:url-open target="dpmq://qmgr/?ParseHeaders=true;ReplyQueue=queue_name" response="xml"/>


Am able to achieve it with below commands

Comment: yes am able to read the header message in the response rule from the queue.